# Render recursive list in view using razor? (was helper method)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I have read that Asp.Net Core doesn't support custom helper methods (`/App_Code/MyHelpers.cshtml`). Is there another way of doing this (recursive rendering of tree structured list)?:

```
@helper BuildMenu(IEnumerable<MenuItem> data, int? parentId = null)
{
    var items = data.Where(d => d.ParentMenuItemId == parentId).OrderBy(i => i.MenuOrder);
    if (items.Any())
    {
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@item.LinkUrl">@item.MenuText</a>
                @BuildMenu(data, item.MenuItemId)
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    }
}
```

Can it be directly implemented into the view? If so, how?

Comment: Razor helpers were *always* a bad idea. Even previously, code like this should have gone into an `HtmlHelper` extension or a child action. In Core, you can still create an `HtmlHelper` extension, but you can also now create custom tag helpers and view components. In this scenario, you probably want a tag helper. View components should only be used when you need to do logic too complex for a view (such as querying a database).